# Python alternative for GNU R

Tags: python, r, open-source

I remember reading about an alternative to GNU R (statistical research system) using Python. I've googled around a bit to find it, but can't seem to. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Another python data analysis tool: http://pandas.pydata.org/

Comment: I Googled **Python alternative for GNU R** and got a few hits for potential projects.

Comment: @Blender I just tried googling the same thing, and this question was the first result. Seems like it's worth answering.

Comment: Thank you i find  just pandas.pydata.org

Comment: pandas, statsmodels and matplotlib together get you roughly similar capabilities to R.

Comment: There is also http://www.sagemath.org/ which is an interactive front end that uses python.  Note that its download size is ~ 1 GB !

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are looking for the RPy2 project: https://rpy2.github.io/

Comment: RPy (note the capitalization) is no longer being developed. RPy2, however, is.  Neither one is an _alternative_ to R in Python but rather a gateway.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I know this useful projects.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you mean ipython with pylab. This is a real alternative, but not exactly for R, but for Matlab.

Comment: I think R, Python, and Matlab share a great many similarities. In their libraries they may vary, and in price, but I think for a lot of things R, Python+numpy+SciPy, and Matlab are equivalent.